# ! Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
   --with-opt-dir
   --without-opt-dir
   --with-opt-include
   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
   --with-opt-lib
   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
   --with-make-prog
   --without-make-prog
   --srcdir=.
   --curdir
   --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
   --with-sqlite3-dir
   --without-sqlite3-dir
   --with-sqlite3-include
   --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
   --with-sqlite3-lib
   --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
   --enable-local
   --disable-local
   Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3dsid22g5kvhv/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
   Results logged to /tmp/build_3dsid22g5kvhv/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
   An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku uses postgresql so you should also use it when developing if you plan to deploy to heroku.  in your Gemfile, remove the line `gem 'sqlite3'` and replace it with `gem 'pg'`.  You need to install the pg server first.

Answer (score 0):

if you have postgre configured at your system, then you can replace

> gem "sqlite3"

with

> gem "pg"

otherwise, add

> group :development do  gem "sqlite3" end group :production do  gem "pg" end

and run bundle as

> bundle install --without production

then push it.

Comment: problem still exist , my gemfile is here,    source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '1.2.1'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.2.0'  
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end


group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end